# macro definition function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define next(x) x + 1
#define prev(x) x - 1
#define mult(x,y) x * y

int main(void) {

int a = 3, b = 4;
printf("%d\n", mult(next(a), prev(b)));
return 0;

}
```

`mult(next(3),prev(4))` expands to `mult(3+1, 4-1)` which is 12. But the answer is 6.

Why is that?

Comment: Try changing `#define next(x) x + 1 to #define next(x) (x+1) and do the same for prev()`

Comment: You may want to follow the standard practice of naming macro identifiers in ALL_CAPS to make it apparent, in code, that it's *special*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

... and `mult(3+1, 4-1)` expands to

```
3+1 * 4-1
```

which results in 3 + 4 - 1 or 6.

In a function like macro definition put parenthesis around each and every parameter and around the whole definition

```
#define next(x) ((x) + 1)
#define prev(x) ((x) - 1)
#define mult(x, y) ((x) * (y))
```